# Why does selecting top 1 from composite index DESC also used to partition by month not select the top value?

Tags: sql-server, index

We have very large database table that I need to select the value of the max id. Given the table size SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableA will not perform well enough.

Table definition (with columns omitted for clarity here)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [id] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
    [timeSampled] [datetime] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] DESC,
    [timeSampled] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

The table is partitioned by month on the timesampled, and because we switch partitions out to another table for archiving data the timeSampled column must be included in the Primary Key.

So, the PK is

```
[id] DESC,
[timeSampled] DESC
```

The table contains rows for May 2013 and June 2013, and the ids increment in date order (i.e. the max id is in June)

When I select the top 1 id from the table as follows

```
SELECT top 1 id
FROM dbo.TableA
WITH (INDEX (PK_TableA))
```

I don't get the max id, instead I get the max id from May (i.e. the very last entry in the May partition).

Any ideas why this is the case? Basically seems to be picking the MAX id from a partition, not max across all partitions

Comment: `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` is undefined. Have you actually tried `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableA` and determined that it does not perform well? If you have how many partitions do you have and what does the plan for that look like? In principle it ought to be able to use the index in each partition to get the single `MAX` quickly then find the `MAX` of those. Do you not get that plan?

Comment: This might be a heavy change, but can't you make the PK index clustered, once that ids and date order increment accordingly? It would most probably speed up your SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableA enough

Comment: Martin Smith, unfortunately the max query does perform slowly. The table is filling at a rate of 3-6 million rows per day and will store data for 6 months before we archive it off.

Comment: @MartinSmith, we have discovered a trick to specify the partition to select max from....

SELECT MAX(id) AS maxId
      FROM dbo.TableA
      WHERE $partition.TableAPartitionFunction_Monthly](timeSampled) = partitionNumber

And this seems to perform well and correctly identify the partition to use.

Comment: @user16484 That would be ok if we didn't have a huge amount of data in the database with only short maintenance periods. Thank you for your suggestion though

Comment: So, as I stated, we have a solution to our problem by forcing a max select from specific partitions. It would however be nice to know why the query I was using in my initial question to select the top 1 id did not work. It seems strange that it does not select the max from all partitions.

Comment: as @MartinSmith said, you'd need a order by for your `top 1` to bring the max

Comment: Adding an order by id does not improve performance for some reason.

Comment: @AdrianPillinger - Yes maybe SQL Server does not currently produce the plan that I described in my first comment. It would probably be possible to use an `APPLY` on `sys.partition_range_values` to get this plan though without being dependant on the assumption that `timeSampled` and `id` are always strictly correlated (though maybe this is a safe enough assumption in your case)

Comment: @MartinSmith Itzik Ben-Gan wrote a very clear explanation and workaround [here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/max-and-min-aggregates-against-partitioned-tables)

Comment: @PaulWhite - Ah thanks very much for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Basically seems to be picking the MAX id from a partition, not max across all partitions*

Writing `TOP (1)` without an `ORDER BY` clause to define which row is 'top' means the query processor is logically free to return *any* row from the set. The query plan selected by the optimizer happens to return a particular row (highest id from the first partition) but you cannot rely on this, even if it were a useful result.

Whenever you use `TOP` you should always specify an `ORDER BY` at the same scope to produce deterministic behaviour - unless you really do not care which row(s) come back.

> *Given the table size SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableA will not perform well enough*

The optimizer is lacking some logic to transform a scalar `MAX` or `MIN` aggregate over a partitioned index to a global aggregate over per-partition aggregates. Itzik Ben-Gan explains the limitation and provides a general workaround in [this article](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/max-and-min-aggregates-against-partitioned-tables).

If the highest partition number is known and *guaranteed not to change*, the workaround to specify a literal partition using the `$partition` function will work, though it may fail in a non-obvious way if the partitioning strategy changes in future.

This 'solution' works by eliminating all but one partition, resulting in a simple seek on one partition of the index.

> *Adding an order by id does not improve performance for some reason*

The same optimizer limitation broadly applies to `TOP (1) ... ORDER BY`. The `ORDER BY` makes the result deterministic, but does not help produce a more efficient plan in this particular case (but see below).

#### Implied Index Keys

Your index is on `id DESC, timeSampled DESC`. In SQL Server 2008 and later, partitioning introduces an extra implied *leading* key on `$partition ASC` (it is always ascending, it is not configurable) making the full index key `$partition ASC, id DESC, timeSampled DESC`.

Since `id` and `timeSampled` increase together (though there is nothing in the schema to guarantee this) you could rewrite the query as `TOP (1) ... ORDER BY $partition DESC, id DESC`. Unfortunately, the `DESC` keys on your index and `ASC` implied leading key `$partition` means the index could not be used to scan just one row from the index in order.

If your index keys were instead `id ASC, timeSampled ASC` the whole index key would be `$partition ASC, id ASC, timeSampled ASC`. This all-`ASC` index could be scanned **backward**, returning just the first row in key order. This row would be guaranteed to have the highest `id` value in the highest-numbered partition. Given the (unenforced) relationship between id and partition id, this would produce the correct result with an optimal execution plan that reads just a single row.

This 'solution' lacks integrity because the id-timeSampled relationship is not enforced, and you probably do not want to rebuild the nonclustered primary key anyway. Nevertheless, I mention it because it may enhance your understanding of how partitioning interacts with indexes.